# How to compress file and take a backup in centos

Tags: linux, centos, server, backup

i have a dedicated server running centos. i want to know, how to take a backup of [my files](https://uploadshub.com/) in [ var/www ] , file size is very big, it can be around 100GB+ , so i want to compress it using zip, or tar.gz anything will work.

can anyone please provide the centos command line for it, how to download all files from var/www by compressing to make the size smaller.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Issue the Command: # tar cvzf backup.tar.gz /var/www

Where:

c - create backup

v - verbose output

z - compress in gzip

f - backup file name

The backup will be created in your current working directory.

Use ls command to list it

Comment: its appearing like this http://prntscr.com/97gl6k ( i am not trying with www, i am testing with another directory first)

Comment: It looks good. backup.tgz will have all the content of /var/games. Even if you delete the /var/games you can retrieve your /var/games content back from backup.tgz file. 

You can compare the size of two files also. Use the `"du -hs /var/www "` and `"du -hs backup.tgz"` to see size difference. 

And to list the content of the backup file without extracting it can be done using command : 

` tar tvf backup.tgz`

Comment: thanks, but where do i find this backup.tgz file in FTP ?? i cant locate it

Comment: got it. thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

Run command : 
tar cvzf backup.tgz /var/www

Comment: where the backup file will go ?

Comment: In current directory backup.tgz will be created